# Having trouble with accessing serial data coming from an Arduino though QSerialPort

Tags: qt

Recently, I have been working on sending data from an Arduino Micro through a serial connection (USB cable) to my computer, where I am trying to use QSerialPort to access it so that I can graph the data in realtime. Although most of the lines of data are good, some become truncated when I read them in using readLine() or readAll(), resulting in loss of data. This is an issue because when I am plotting two variables in real time, and it fails to read the second variable, my graph results suffer. Additionally, that missed data is then tacked on later lines of data, which messes everything up more. To be clear, Arduino is sending the data fine, as using the serial monitor shows that all lines of data are complete.

Here is the main of a program that is reading the data from the Micro, and outputting it to a file (this is also getting the data error, and is a much cleaner program to discover the cause of the error on).

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QString>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFile>

QT_USE_NAMESPACE

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QSerialPortInfo info("COM6");
    // Check info of the port
            qDebug() << "Name        : " << info.portName();
            qDebug() << "Manufacturer: " << info.manufacturer();
            qDebug() << "Busy: " << info.isBusy() << endl;

// Initialize Serial
QSerialPort serial;
serial.setPortName("COM6");
serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

QFile file("C:\\Users\\Keenan\\Documents\\serialTest\\arduinoData.txt");//open file

if(!file.exists())
 {
    qDebug()<<"File Doesn't Exist";
 }
if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text))
 {
     QMessageBox::information(0, "error", file.errorString());
 };

QTextStream stream(&file);


while (serial.isOpen())
 {
  serial.waitForReadyRead(-1);
  QString data;
  data = serial.readAll();
  qDebug() << "Data has been found: " << data <<endl;
  stream << data << endl;
 }

file.close();
qDebug() << "Done" << endl;
return a.exec();
}
```

Here is the Arduino code of note that is being sent every 2 seconds (I've replaced variables with constant values to make the error more clear):

```
Serial.print("1");
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print("2");
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print("3");
Serial.print(",");
Serial.print("4");
Serial.print(",");
Serial.println("5");
```

When I run the program, this is what I read into my text file:

```
1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1
,2,3,4,5

1
,2,3,4,5

1,
2,3,4,5

1,2,
3,4,5

1,2,3,
4,5

1,2,3,4
,5

1,2,3,4,5


1,2,3,4,5


1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,3,4,5
```

As you see, 1,2,3,4,5 gets screwed up around the end, but eventually fixes itself for unknown reasons. The Baudrate for the Arduino is 9600, which matches what I've set it at. Ignoring the primitiveness of this code, does anyone know why it would truncate data like that? I've been stuck on this for days now trying different things, and I'd really like to get past this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not an issue. `QSerialPort` works as expected. In your case, using `serial.readAll()`, you can recieve `1,2,` or `3,4,5\r\n` or even `3,4,5\r\n1,2,`.

Comment: @Meefte: The problem is that I need it to always read 1,2,3,4,5 in one line, and not occasionally read just 1,2, for example. If I am going to be graphing with data, when it doesn't give me the entirety of it, it messes my graphing program up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `QSerialPort::readAll()` it's just reading whatever has become available on the serial port which will occasionally not be the entire output string, the way I've handled it previously is to read all the data into a `QString` buffer and then when a line ending character (`\n` or `\r`) is in the buffer using `split('\n')` to get the actual line of data.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that. Thanks